# pandas to_numeric producing valueerror

Tags: python, pandas

I am unable to make to_numeric to work in the code below:

```
tt = ['123.00','10,614,163,994.00']
pd.to_numeric(tt)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "10,614,163,994.00" at position 1
```

please help.

Comment: As a general note, it's very difficult and error prone for computers to parse mixed formats (whether it's numbers or dates or something else) so at a minimum you want to normalize data into one particular format before attempting conversion.  For example, if you added a 3rd number here '123,456' there's no way to know if the ',' is a decimal point or thousands separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`to_numeric` cannot handle the `,` as seperator for thousands, millions, ..

You should preprocess `tt` by something like `tt = [n.replace(',','') for n in tt]`

Answer (score 0):

The second value in `tt` is not a number, in the limited definition of number for many parsers. Just remove the commas before trying to do the conversion.

```
tt = ['123.00','10,614,163,994.00']
tt = [x.replace(',','') for x in tt]
pd.to_numeric(tt)
```

Comment: Please add some details/clarification to your code.

Comment: You should annotate your answer